# babelify doesn't take effect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "dongio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:less": "less ./app/modules/*/*.less > ./public/stylesheets/style.css",
    "build:js": "browserify -t babelify app/routes/*.js > public/javascripts/bundle.js",
    "start": "npm run build:less | npm run build:js | node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^2.0.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why but babelify doesn't work at all ? I receive the following error :

```
layout.js: Unexpected token (11:22)
   9 | 
  10 |     render() {
> 11 |         let navbar = (<nav>
     |                       ^
  12 |                     <div>
  13 |                         <ul>
  14 |                             <li><Link to='login'>Login</Link></li>
```

Any idea why this happens ? I also put it under devDependency , installed it globally, no help.

Comment: does moving the presets from package.json to an actual .babelrc do anything? i had a similar problem with gulp that didnt work until i made a physical babelrc

Comment: @PhilVarg :  just posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally my problem was solved by changing the `build:js` command. I don't know why `browserify` transform setting in `package.json` doesn't work. I had to explicitly preset the browserify in the command as in the following :

```
{
  "name": "dongio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:less": "less ./app/modules/*/*.less > ./public/stylesheets/style.css",
    "build:js": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] app/routes/*.js* > public/javascripts/bundle.js",
    "start": "npm run build:js | node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^2.0.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Note that you have to npm install `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-react` to make this work.